# runtime error: signed integer overflow: 964632435 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Tags: c++

I'm solving the problem of reversing an integer and got the error as below :

```
Line 8: Char 20: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 964632435 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
```

My code is :

```
public:
    int reverse(int x) {
        int last=x%10;
        int rev=0;
        while(x){
            last=x%10;
            rev=rev*10+last;
            x=x/10;
        }
        return rev;
    }
};
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error. I'm a newbie to programming. I am not able to get the concept. Please someone explain it to me and how can I proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

I get the answer. Actually there is integer overflow when we have `rev` approaching `INT_MAX`. We check beforehand whether or this statement would cause an overflow or not. Actually i found the below solution on internet and it worked

```
 int reverse(int x) {
        int last=x%10;
        int rev=0;
        while(x!=0){
            last=x%10;
            if (rev>=INT_MAX/10){
                if (rev>INT_MAX/10){
                    return 0;
                }else{
                    if (last>7){
                      return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (rev<=INT_MIN/10){
                if (rev<INT_MIN/10){
                    return 0;
                }else{
                    if (last<-8){
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            rev=rev*10+last;
            x=x/10;
        }
        return rev;
    }
```